# Python - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'zip' and 'int'

Tags: numpy, pygame, openai-gym

I am modifying some Python 2.7 code to be compatible with Python 3.7. I made as many edits as I could, until this happens:

```py
C:\Users\AyazA\Desktop\schema-games>python schema_games/breakout/play.py StandardBreakout
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
[34m--------------------------------------------------------------------------------[0m
[34mStarting interactive game. Press <ESC> at any moment to terminate.[0m
[34m--------------------------------------------------------------------------------[0m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "schema_games/breakout/play.py", line 93, in <module>
    play_game(getattr(games, variant), debug=debug, cheat_mode=cheat_mode)
  File "schema_games/breakout/play.py", line 54, in play_game
    play(env, fps=fps, keys_to_action=keys_to_action, zoom=ZOOM_FACTOR)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\gym\utils\play.py", line 79, in play
    env.reset()
  File "C:\Users\AyazA\Desktop\schema-games\schema_games\breakout\core.py", line 301, in reset
    self.layout_sanity_check()
  File "C:\Users\AyazA\Desktop\schema-games\schema_games\breakout\core.py", line 473, in layout_sanity_check
    all_occupied_nzis = [nzi for obj in considered_objects
  File "C:\Users\AyazA\Desktop\schema-games\schema_games\breakout\core.py", line 474, in <listcomp>
    for nzi in obj.offset_nzis if obj.visible]
  File "C:\Users\AyazA\Desktop\schema-games\schema_games\breakout\objects.py", line 190, in offset_nzis
    offset_nzis_from_position(self._nzis, self._position)
  File "C:\Users\AyazA\Desktop\schema-games\schema_games\breakout\utils.py", line 57, in offset_nzis_from_position
    return zip(*(np.add(nzis, np.array(pos))).T)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'zip' and 'int'
```

I tried unzipping the contents of the zipped tuple, but it was of no use. I tried even further to look into forcing the two to add (both `pos` and `nzis` are of type `ndarray`), only to not work. Is this another Python 2.7 incompatibility that I am missing? [Here](https://github.com/ayaz-amin/schema-games) is the source code and the [corresponding repository](https://github.com/vicariousinc/schema-games) that I forked from

Comment: if you have `zip()` then you may have to convert ot `list()` and then to something else - like `numpy.array`

Comment: Tried that, but it returns a ```TypeError: iteration over a 0d array```.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables - ie. `print(nzis, pos, np.array(pos), np.add(nzis, np.array(pos)), (np.add(nzis, np.array(pos))).T)`. It can also show in which moment it has problem.

Comment: OK, so I just realized that ```zip``` in Py3 no longer has the same functionality as Py27. I fixed up lines with ```list(zip)``` instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False alarm. It was a collection of problems in the file itself. There were many instances of the `zip` function that needed to be replaced with `list(zip)` instead.

Comment: Just to give you a reason for this - `zip` output changed between 2.x - 3.x from an iterable to a generator.  `numpy.array` will try to create arrays from iterables but not generators (since generators can in theory generate infinitely large output).